# ¿Como puedo desvincular y re-vincular binds sin perder las funciones enlasadas en Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un programa en Python Tkinter en el cual necesito desvincular una cantidad N de binds y en otro momento revincularlos sin perder las funciones antes vinculadas. Aquí paso un codigo de ejemplo para que quede entendible la idea:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button

ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("200x50")

def detach():
    print("Elimina los binds.")
    print()

def rebind():
    print("Vuelve a crearlos tal como eran.")
    print()

def funcion(Event):
    print("Este bind deja de funcionar al ejecutar la función 'detach' y vuelve a funcionar cuando se ejecuta 'rebind'.")
    print()

Button(ventana, text="un-bind", command=detach).pack()
Button(ventana, text="re-bind", command=rebind).pack()

ventana.bind("<Return>", funcion)
```

Debido a circunstancias dentro de mi programa que es mejor que no sepan para evitar confusión, no me sirve usar condicionales como `if(not deleted):`, necesito que el propio Tkinter no ejecute el bind.
Cualquier cosa que no entiendan me preguntan. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya solucioné la duda. Probé este código y funciona:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button

ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("200x50")

class togglebind():
    def __init__(Self,widget):
        Self.widget = widget
        Self.events = widget.bind()
        Self.binds = []

        for event in Self.events:
            Self.binds.append(widget.bind(event))

    def detach(Self):
        for event in Self.events:
            Self.widget.unbind(event)

    def rebind(Self):
        for event, bind in tuple(zip(Self.events, Self.binds)):
            Self.widget.bind(event, bind)

def funcion(Event):
    print("este bind deja de funcionar al ejecutar la función 'detach' y vuelve a funcionar cuando se ejecuta 'rebind'")

ventana.bind("<Return>", funcion)
tb = togglebind(ventana)

Button(ventana, text="un-bind", command=tb.detach).pack()
Button(ventana, text="re-bind", command=tb.rebind).pack()
```